# retrieve the Json data to the ITest

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Goal:
Get the data from json to the "test: ITest[];"  and then display it by using console.log

Problem:
The code doesn't work. What part am I missing?

Info:
I'm newbie in Angular

Thank you!

---

Service

```
  getData2(): Observable<ITest[]> {
    return this.http.get<ITest[]>('https://api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs');
  }

export interface ITest {
  login: string,
  node_id: string
}
```

---

Component

```
  public test: ITest[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData2()
  }


  getData2() {
    this.asdfService.getData2().subscribe(res => { this.test = res });

    console.log(this.test)
  };
export interface ITest {
  login: string,
  node_id: string
}
```

Comment: Could you show the full code of the component? (not the HTML, just the class)

Comment: Also, when you say `The code doesn't work.`, what is happening? is there a compilation error? runtime error? there is no visual feedback?

Comment: Move your console.log() **inside** the callback function passed to subscribe(). An http request is **asynchronous**. You can't expect the response to be available immediately after you sent the request. It will only be available later, and the callback will then be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `getData2` returns an Observable, which may be resolved some time later, but the `console.log` call is right after the `subscribe`, so by the time `console.log` is invoked, the Observable may not have resolved.

Try this:

```
  getData2() {
    this.asdfService.getData2().subscribe(res => { 
        this.test = res
        console.log(this.test)
    });  
  }
```

That way, you only invoke `console.log` when you get a new value for `this.test`

Comment: Is it only because I use Observable that you have to write this.test inside of subscribe?

Comment: Will I still get the data from this.test after executing getData2? For my it looks like that it is empty?

Comment: As Observables make your code asynchronous then you need to assign that variable inside of the `subscribe`, and printing the value of the variable also needs to happen there. About the second question, There is no guarantee `this.test` will have a value after executing `getData2`, the reason is that the code is asynchronous: only when the function passed to `subscribe` is executed you'll have a value in that variable. I think it's worth to read this: https://angular.io/guide/observables

Answer (score 0):

welcome to angular. only problem with your code is

```
  getData2() {
    this.asdfService.getData2().subscribe(res => { this.test = res });

    console.log(this.test)
  };
```

should be like this

```
  getData2() {
    this.asdfService.getData2().subscribe(res => { 
       this.test = res;
       console.log(this.test);
    });
  };
```

the code within subscribe is called asyncronously so if you don't place `console.log` in subscribe it doesn't wait for `this.test = res` to get executed. this is called reactive programming and it is a fundamental building block of angular.

[this](https://angular.io/guide/observables) is a good starting point for beginning.